# Can a 20 amp GFCI outlet be daisy chained to 15 amp outlets

Tags: electrical, receptacle

I am using 20 amp breaker. My starting point is a 20 amp GFCI outlet.

I have it daisy chained to four 15 amp outlets. Is allowed by code?

Comment: that is assuming the circuit is wired with #12 and not #14 make sure to check the wire size before proceeding.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is specifically allowed by code (NEC).

A 20A general use circuit can supply 15A or 20A receptacles.

[image]